# Xbox - How would I boot from a Linux livecd?

Tags: linux, boot, livecd, xbox360

Is there a secret button combination like a PC's F2 or Delete that forces an Xbox to boot from a CD?

Comment: How is this off-topic?! Even if this were off-topic, at least have the decency to move this to a relevant Stack Overflow subforum.

Answer (score 1):

It's likely you need to have the console 'modded' at least in some way. There may be other ways... But it looks like it will not be as simple as putting in a regular livecd and pressing buttons.

A lot of the guides and stories are a few years old now, so subsequent patches and hardware changes may make some of the guides invalid now.

Have a look at some guides and communities around this:

> http://www.free60.org/Main_Page
>
> http://www.xbox-scene.com/articles/linux-install.php
>
> Keep searching...
>   http://google.com/search?q=install+linux+on+xbox+360

Comment: The Xbox-Scene tutorial describes booting from an "Xbox-Live" CD, using a keyboard to enter a username and password. The tutorial neglects to mention how the user booted from the CD.